# "On My iPhone" (local) option missing in Calender?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I found this question posted elsewhere on the web, but with no answer. I just noticed the same thing while developing a calendar app, and it seems to be a problem for me to:

> I've always had my contacts & calender on my iPhone *locally* and my
>   phone used to call this group "On my iPhone"... after iOS5 and iCloud
>   update, the only option is iCloud. There is no "On my iPhone" option
>   anymore, which I need for when I'm travelling abroad and have no data
>   connection to update the iCloud's online contacts, I looked online and
>   they said Importing SIM contacts would bring this back, and again it
>   dosent give me the option for On My iPhone, the only option is iCloud.
>   How do I bring "On my iPhone" or *offline* contacts back.?

When I examine the event store (EKEventStore) from within my program, I can see that the calendars array contains local calendars, including the custom calendar created by my application. But I don't see these local calendars on my device. Also, I don't see how to enable them on the device.

This may have happened after upgrading to iOS 5.0, 5.1 or 5.1.1, but I can't be sure. It was possible at one time for me to see on the device both the set of local calendars and the set of iCloud calendars. Now I only see iCloud calendars.